# Necessary conditions for a function to be convex: $\textbf{dom}f$ AND $\textbf{epi}f$ must be convex sets? Do they imply each other?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

According the p. 67 of [Boyd's book on convexity](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex if $\textbf{dom}f$ is a convex set and if for all $x, y \in \textbf{dom}f$, and $\theta$ with $0 \le \theta \le 1$, we have
$$
f(\theta x+ (1-\theta)y)\le \theta (f(x) + (1-\theta)f(y)
$$
Moreover according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function), a function $f$ is convex if its epigraph is convex. Does those conditions automatically imply each other and, if yes, how can we prove it?

Comment: Boyd's book says no such thing.  Did you miss the "and if" after "is a convex set"?

Comment: You've omitted a large part of the definition from Boyd's book.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @RobertIsrael and RobArthan. I completed the definition of Boyd's book. Does the question make more sense now?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are equivalent definitions.  Note that $f(\theta x + (1-\theta) y) \le \theta f(x) + (1-\theta) f(y)$ where $0 \le t \le 1$ says that $\theta (x, f(x)) + (1-\theta) (y, f(y))$ is in the epigraph of $f$, and then of course so is $\theta (x,s) + (1-\theta) (y,t)$ if $s \ge f(x)$ and $t \ge f(y)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @RobertIsrael. How does that imply that $\textbf{dom}f$ is a convex set?

Comment: $\mathbf{dom} f$ is the image of the epigraph under a linear transformation. Linear transformations map convex sets to convex sets.